# sqlite3 unable to open database file with flask and docker

Tags: python, docker, sqlite, flask

I have a backend project where the final result is stored in fraud_detection.db. I am experimenting with flask and docker and don't seem to be able to get everything running.

This is my file tree

```
DE-Project/
│
├── .dockerignore
├── docker-compose.yaml
├── Dockerfile.train_model
├── Dockerfile.producer
├── Dockerfile.consumer
├── Dockerfile.frontend
│
├── shared/
│   └── requirements.txt
│   └── kaggle.json
│
├── train_model/
│   ├── train_model.py
│   └── functions.py
│
└── make_predictions/
│   └── producer.py
│   └── consumer.py
│   └── functions.py
│   └── fraud_detection.db
└── frontend/
    ├── app.py
    ├── test.py
    └── templates/
        └── index.html
```

This is the flask app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import sqlite3
import os

app = Flask(__name__)

# Set the path to the templates folder explicitly
template_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'templates')
app.template_folder = template_path

# Get the absolute path to the directory containing this script
script_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

# Construct the absolute path to the database file
db_file_path = os.path.join(script_dir, 'make_predictions/fraud_detection.db')

@app.route('/')
def index():
    # Connect to the SQLite database using the absolute path
    conn = sqlite3.connect(db_file_path)

    # Create a cursor object to execute SQL queries
    cur = conn.cursor()

    # Execute a query to fetch all entries (assuming your table is named 'potential_fraud')
    sqlite_select_Query = "SELECT * FROM potential_fraud LIMIT 10;"

    # Execute the query
    cur.execute(sqlite_select_Query)

    # Fetch all the entries
    record = cur.fetchall()

    # Close the database connection
    conn.close()

    # Render the HTML template with the entries
    return render_template('index.html', entries=record)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Run the Flask app on port 5000
```

This is my Dockerfile:

```
# Use an official Python runtime as a parent image
FROM python:3.8

# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
COPY . /app

# Install any needed packages specified in requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Expose port 5000 to the outside world
EXPOSE 5000

# Run app.py when the container launches
CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

When I run it  in docker I get this error when I access it via localhost:

```
  File "app.py", line 20, in index
    conn = sqlite3.connect(db_file_path)
sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file
```

I understand that this error usually happens when something is wrong with the file path. I tested the connection with test.py which worked fine:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('make_predictions/fraud_detection.db')
cur = conn.cursor()

sqlite_select_Query = "SELECT * FROM potential_fraud LIMIT 1;"
cur.execute(sqlite_select_Query)
record = cur.fetchall()
print(record)
cur.close()

conn.close()
print("The SQLite connection is closed")
```

Is something in my app.py wrong? Maybe my Dockerfile or both?

Comment: Your `db_file_path` is wrong.  You're specifically looking for it in the directory that contains the script, which is `frontend`, but you need to start looking one level up.  You need to add a `".."` in there.

Comment: Not only that, but sqlite3 will just create a new database file when you open a connection on a new path - the fact that it says it cannot open the file _strongly_ suggests that you have some non-db file with that name on the path you point to

Comment: when I print db_file_path I seem to get the correct path: `/app/make_predictions/fraud_detection.db` though

Comment: Can you change this to use a standalone relational database, in a separate container?  That will get around the "where is the file" problem you have now.  Mounting persistent storage to hold the database file will also be a problem, since in your layout it's in the middle of your source tree.  Dealing with "files" in Docker in general can be surprisingly tricky, and alternatives that don't need "files" _per se_ are often easier to manage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem. The trick, or my solution, was to put the database into a shared drive. I specified it in the docker-compose, consumer.py and the frontend. This worked. I guess an even better solution would to have a real database setup in a completely standalone container. But this works for now :)